# how to find row value of particular table data in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have a php table with values. I want make two table data as editable. I have table headers `Task, Duedate, Staff, Department`. The `td` values are pulled from database using laravel eloquent.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th scope="col">Task</th><th scope="col">Duedate</th><th scope="col">Staff</th><th scope="col">Department</th></tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($tasks as $task)

                    <input type="text" id="taskid" name="taskid" value="{{$task->id}}" hidden>

                    <tr class="tabletd"><td scope="col" >{{$task->task}}</td>
                        <td scope="col" contenteditable="true">
                            <input type="date" name="duedate" id="duedate" class='form-control form-control-sm' value="{{$task->duedate}}" style="width:135px;" >
                        </td>

                        <td scope="col">{{$task->user->name}}</td><td scope="col">{{$task->department->title}}</td>

            </tr></table>   @endforeach
```

and I using ajax to update the values in server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('change','#duedate',function(){
    var duedate=$(this).val();
    var id = $('#taskid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('duedateupdate')!!}',
        data:{'id':id, 'duedate':duedate},
        success:function(data){
            document.getElementById("updatemsg").hidden = false; 
            setTimeout( function (){
                document.getElementById("updatemsg").hidden = true; 
            }, 2000);

        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
});
```

It is working well. But it updates only the first row of the table. How can I update values in the other rows.

Comment: avoid using duplicate ids in html document

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the input id "duedate"

Change the id to class

```
<input type="date" name="duedate" class='form-control form-control-sm duedate' value="{{$task->duedate}}" style="width:135px;" >
```

and then in your event listener use the class selector :

```
$(document).on('change','.duedate',function(){
```

This should give you the desired result

--- edit after the comment below: -----

look at the selector here :
`var id = $('#taskid').val();`

again, you are using an id ( an id will always only select one element), rather use a data value in the input like this:

`<input type="date" data-task-id="{{$task->id}}" class="duedate" class='form-control form-control-sm' value="{{$task->duedate}}" style="width:135px;" >`

then you can use this in your ajax :

`var id = $(this).data( 'task-id' );`

I have found that sometimes data() gives me problems, if that happens, use this:

`var id = $(this).attr( 'data-task-id' );`

Comment: No.. Still it updates duedate in the first row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have code edited my code like below and it works well

```
<input type="date" name="duedate"  contenteditable="true" data-id="{{$task->id}}" data-column="duedate"  class="form-control form-control-sm duedate"  value="{{$task->duedate}}" style="width:135px;" >


$(document).on('change','.duedate',function(){
    var duedate = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('duedateupdate')!!}',
        data:{'id':id,'duedate':duedate},
        success:function(data){

        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
});
```